# combinations possible of distributing 8 apples to 4 people

Tags: combinatorics

I saw a problem where you need to distribute 8 apples to 4 different people where there is also a possibility of one or more of them getting 0 apples too. How do you compute in combinatorics the number of total combinations. The answer is given as 165. I am unable to deduce a combinatoric term for the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to state the problem carefully.  It sounds like the people are labeled-then this becomes a [stars and bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)problem.  Since you seem to allow that some people don't get any apples, distribute $12$ apples to $4$ people, requiring that each gets at least one.  Now you have to choose four places of eleven to place dividers, so the answer is ${11 \choose 3}=165$ but I am not confident I am answering the correct problem.

Comment: $+1\quad $ Congratulations, b.t.w. $\gt 100$K!

Comment: There are 8 apples and 4 people. From there how did you get to 12 apples to 4 people and get to 11C3. can you slightly simplify it or show me a reference for the method you are using. I understand the method where you have  8 stars and 3 bars depicting the seperation between 4 people and then you see that you can combine 8+3=11 and pick 3 out of them. I just wanted to know if there is a more intuitive way of understanding from the mathematics of it. Sorry for asking a very silly clarification. I am a student and am looking at other ways of thinking about the problem.

Comment: 12 apples takes care of the fact that you allow some people not to get any.  An arrangement of 8 apples to 4 people where some people may not have any apples corresponds to an arrangement of 12 apples to 4 people were everybody has at least one.  Just do the 12/4, then steal one apple from each.  In the stars and bars solution, only one bar is allowed between any given pair of stars, so each interval includes at least one star.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, the answer is $11\choose3$ , since once you have chosen the 3rd divider, the allocation is already determined, so the answer is , as you said, $11\choose3$; the general formula is :

$(n+k-1)\choose(k-1)$= $(8+4-1)\choose(4-1)$=$11\choose3$=$165$

Basically, once you have put the $(k-1)$st divider, the partition is completely-described.

Comment: Ya your calculation is correct. But given the problem how do i know to take (n+k-1). I understand the (k-1) divisions. But can you clarify about how you mathematically chose (n+k-1).

Comment: Ya, please see my explanation below, and let me know if you agree with it. I changed my user name because my account was wiped out when I tried to register.

Answer (score 0):

Reply to talasila, but I don't have enough points, because my many BFD (and other) accounts I try to open have been wiped out to 0 points every time I try to officially sign up using my e-mail.

Eh, ya, just like in the proof for stars and bars, you use 8 apples and you want to have 3 additional spaces to use as dividers ( after you use the 3rd divider, the assignment has been determined). You then have 8 spaces+ 3 spaces( the dividers) anywhere between the 8 apples; each choice of dividers determines a combination, e.g., let $D_i; i=1,2,3$ be the dviders, and let $A_i; i=1,2,..,8$ be the apples .If you have:

$A_1, A_2, D_1, A_3, A_4, A_5, D_2, A_6, D_3$

Means you assign 2 apples to #1, 3 apples to #2, 1 apple to #3, and --this why you use just 3 dividers--all the remaining 2 apples to #4

You can use up to 11=8+3-1 spaces, because the 3 dividers can go anywhere from being 1 left of the 1st apple and 1 right of the last apple. Any assignment of dividers is equivalent to a distribution of apples.